# Is this differential equation separable??

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Just a quick question... I have the equation:

$$\frac{dw}{dy} w^{-2}=0$$

Is this separable? i.e. can I go :

$$\begin{align}
\frac{dw}{dy} w^{-2}&=0 \\[8pt]
(w^{-2}) \,dw&=(0)\,dy \tag{*} \\[8pt]
-w^{-1}&=A
\end{align}$$
and thus
$$w = B$$ with $A,B$ being arbitrary constants with $B \not= 0$

Is this ok? The only thing I'm wondering about is the starred line... can I separate the equation like that with only a zero on the RHS?

Comment: Why not multiply by $w^{-2}$ and get $dw/dy = 0$ ...

Comment: @GEdgar Wasnt sure if I wouldn't lose generality by doing that though I did think about it. I see it would give the same result though. So either idea is valid then ?

Comment: ....or rather by $w^2$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, your reasoning is valid.

The reason why you're not used to applying separation of variables to a situation like that is because it's actually unnecessary: you have the product of two terms equalling zero, so one of them must be zero. $w^{-2}$ is never zero, regardless of $w$, so $\frac{dw}{dy}$ is zero. So $w$ is constant.

Comment: Aight thanks a lot .. Yeah its been a while since I've had to use ODEs and I've forgotten all the rules. Thanks for the clarification